# Creating a quiz with randomly generated questions using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a quiz in android using my firebase database, in this, I am hoping to have randomly generation questions that don't repeat.

As of now, I have been successful in developing a quiz that randomly generated questions, although the same question can be repeated.

For eg: 
I ask four questions, these are taking from my firebase database, any of my questions can be used. In question 1 it may display, the question with id 4. Question 2 may display the question with id 4 again as there is nothing there to say question 4 can't be displayed.

```
 FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userid = Objects.requireNonNull(user).getUid();
        mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Review Questions");

        if(total >4) {

            description.setText("Completed");
            details();

        }
        else
        {
            int n = rand.nextInt(9);
            int n2 = n +1;
            //if the number has been selected, so add the selected items to a list.
            DatabaseReference databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child("Plastic").child(String.valueOf(n2));
            databaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final Question question = dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                    t1_question.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(question).getQuestion());
                    b1.setText(question.getAnswer1());
                    b2.setText(question.getAnswer2());
                    b3.setText(question.getAnswer3());
                    b4.setText(question.getAnswerCorrect());
```

This is my original code, I got the idea maybe if I add all questions to an array list then each time I ask a question I can simply remove that question from the array.

I have attempted that this way:

```
DatabaseReference databaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child("Plastic");
            databaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    question= dataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                    list.add(new Question(question.getQuestion(),question.getDifficulty(), question.getAnswer1(),question.getAnswer2(), question.getAnswer3(), question.getAnswerCorrect(),question.getCategory(),question.getId() ,question.getDescription(), question.getScore()));


               }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
              x = list.size();
                    n = rand.nextInt(x);


            if(total >4) {

                description.setText("Completed");
                details();

            }
            else
            {
                        //declare as a global variable, in the class then access
               question = list.get(n);
                        t1_question.setText(question.getQuestion());
                        b1.setText(question.getAnswer1());
                        b2.setText(question.getAnswer2());
                        b3.setText(question.getAnswer3());
                        b4.setText(question.getAnswerCorrect());
```

For some reason the questions won't add to my array, I can't seem to understand why. Would there be a better solution for this?

Comment: declare an integer array and put the generated id into it, at each random check if that id existes in the array if not continue else regenerate an other id.

Answer (score 0):

`databaseref.addValueEventListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query has finished.  The callback you provide to it will be invoked some time later, when the data is available.  Your code goes on to assume that `list` contains some data, when it actually does not yet.  What you will have to do instead is only work with the contents of `list` after the callback is invoked.  So, you will need to put the followup code inside the callback itself, or something else to make sure that it gets invoked only after `list` is populated.

Comment: Sorry, I am not fully understanding what you mean, I can't understand why it doesn't populate the list? As it is asynchronous should the data from firebase not immediately be added to the Array list of Question? Further on I am then trying to call from the list but of course, the list isn't populated. I also have tried to add in the data directly under the database ref.addValueEventListener call although this results in blank return.

Comment: I have removed the ` x = list.size();
                n = rand.nextInt(x)` from the `databaseref.addValueEventListener` and have further created a new method so the code is not executed untill the listener is complete. It still is empty